# Expose host port 80 of a Dockerized Django app deployed on AWS Fargate

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-fargate

I have a very simple Django rest framework (DRF) app that is dockerized and deployed on AWS ECS with Fargate. I created a security group to expose the port 8000 on the inbound rules and was able to see the app at public IP `12.34.56:78:8000/`

I wanted to have the app run on port 80, but don't know how to. Do I need to expose 80 on the Dockerfile and specify that port when creating the task definition? Or do I need to set up nginx to pass HTTP requests to port 8000 internally?

Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.12

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

# Expose the Django development server port
EXPOSE 8000

# # Start the Django development server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Task definition:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:123:task-definition/app-task:12",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "container-name",
            "image": "dockerhub/app:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "default",
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/app-api-task",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this in several different ways, but following your line of reasoning:

You can change the port of your application and also in the Dockerfile to port 80 and configure the same port for the sec-group.

Another way to do this is to [add an ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-application-load-balancer.html) which will forward requests on port 80 to the container on port 8000.

Another possibility is to create another container with nginx, and configure it as a reverse proxy for your application, this last way is a little more difficult to do, see this [article](https://dev.to/sfrancavilla/deploy-web-apps-nginx-to-ecs-with-docker-198i).

Comment: Thank you. I had a lot of trouble deploying a multi-container image with docker compose. Today I learned about aws-cli compose that can achieve it thanks to your link. I ended up going with AWS Lambda, after realizing the cost of Fargate.